# How do I bind the background of a data grid row to specific color?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

I have a observable collection that binds to a data grid. I also have in the view model a color property and I want to bind the background of each row in the data grid to the color property on the vm.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can bind the `Background` in the `RowStyle` for `DataGrid`

```
<DataGrid ...>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding MyBackground}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <!-- ... -->
</DataGrid>
```

This will work if `MyBackground` is a `Brush`. You mention in your question that you have a `Color`, if this is the case you can use this instead

```
<Setter Property="Background">
    <Setter.Value>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding MyColor}"/>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```