# WPF Datagrid-Change background color of the row for which the button is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, background

I have a data grid in my wpf application. I wants that when user clicks on any button in the datagrid the corresponding row should be red. I think we can do it by using event trigger but i really don't know how to use it.

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgEmp" Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" >          
        <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=Age}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete" Width="*">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="Delete selected row"></Button>                              
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can set up a colour property in each row, bind this to the rows background colour and change it as the SelectedItem changes.

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
       <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RowColour}" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Comment: Does not work for me.  Neither does  
`<DataGrid.RowBackground>
 <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding RowColor}" />
</DataGrid.RowBackground>`
  nor  
`<DataGrid.Resources>
 <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RowColor}" />
 </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>`
  In any of these cases i get row's background set to form's color.

Comment: @Astrogator Are you getting any binding errors? Are you binding to a colour in the collection or the ancestor or the collection? This does work.

Comment: The trick is: if `RowColor` is of type `Color`, one must wrap it in `<SolidColorBrush>` element, as shown in answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339509/.  Otherwise `RowColor` must be a `Brush`.