# Bind datagrid row color to cell value in WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid, styling

I have a datagrid in WPF where one of the columns is the color I would like the row to be set. How can I set the color of the row to the value (e.g. #FF7B68EE) of this field?

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Name="dgBank" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=bankTable.dataTable.DefaultView}" AutoGenerateColumns="TRUE" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" />
```

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339509/how-do-i-bind-the-background-of-a-data-grid-row-to-specific-color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the answer that @codeBlue pointed me towards in the comments on my question. [How do I bind the background of a data grid row to specific color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339509/how-do-i-bind-the-background-of-a-data-grid-row-to-specific-color)

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Name="dgBank" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=bankTable.dataTable.DefaultView}" AutoGenerateColumns="TRUE" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding colorColumn}"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```